# LingPipe Text Processing API

Tags: java, api, text, nlp

This is a question only to those who 
already used the LingPipe.
My question is how to load up the GENIA corpus
for Part of Speech tagging. 
When I start parsing it I get an error saying
that I got out of memory heap.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the JVM with more memory.  See the answer to [Why do I get an OutOfMemoryError when inserting 50,000 objects into HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235047/why-do-i-get-an-outofmemoryerror-when-inserting-50-000-objects-into-hashmap).

Answer (score 1):

Set an environment variable to allow for a bigger maximum heap size e.g. -Xmx2g gives max heap of 2gb memory